# Circular motion in a cone, velocity dependence of height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I'm attempting to solve the circular motion problem below:

---

You spin a marble around the inside of a large funnel, such that it follows a circular path. How does the height $h$ above the bottom of the cone at which the marble spins depend upon its rotation speed?
[image]

---

**Attempted solution:**

We have that $\sin{\theta} = \frac{r}{h}$. Therefore, $h = \frac{r}{\tan{\theta}}$.

Also, $a_c = \frac{v^2}{r}$ $\to$ $r = \frac{v^2}{a_c}$.

So, $h = \frac{\frac{v^2}{a_c}}{\tan{\theta}} = \frac{\tan{\theta} \cdot v^2}{a_c}$

---

I'm not quite sure where to go from here (perhaps I'm not on the right track? I feel pretty confident in this, however). I know it to be more-or-less an ideal banking problem, however here I'm looking for $h$ (often, one is asked to optimize $\theta$). I cannot seem to construct a system that leads to a solution.

Note that, as opposed to asking for my work to be checked, I'm looking for insight into how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
mg=N \sin \theta \\
m\frac{v^2}{r}=N \cos \theta\\
r=h \tan \theta \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
where $\vec{N}$ is the normal force of the cone against the gravity,
solving this system you obtain that $v= \sqrt{gh}$.
N.B you've done a mistake in trigonometric relation

Answer (score 0):

This problem is ideal for the Virial Theorem, which relates the average kinetic energy ($\bar T$) and total potential energy ($U$) in a $r^n$ potential via:

$$ 2\bar T = nU $$

With $n=1$ and $U = mgh$:

$$ 2 \frac 1 2 mv^2 = mgh $$

or

$$ v = \sqrt{gh} $$

(N.B.: There are no errors in my trigonometry because there is no trigonometry).